# Should I ask a question that has already been asked and answered, but for which the answer is no longer true?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/181/635) was correct when it was first posted, but the instructions no longer work (confirmed by several other users in the comments on this answer). In fact, I am not sure what the current solution is, or even if there is a solution.

I want to ask a new question: "How can I sync multiple calendars from my google account to windows phone?" But this seems like a duplicate question, even though the original has an incorrect answer.

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Hello Matthew. As soon as you have a real answer you can post a new one. But if you only want to say that the currently answer is no longer accurately I think is better you post as a comment.

Comment: By the way, I found a new solution that works for Windows 8 and Windows Phone. I will post in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked into the official method of doing this yet, but as a starting point for discussion...

I might consider leaving a comment on answers (and maybe down voting) that don't work, then edit the question to state that the answers no longer work (this should bump it up to the main page).

Answer (score 1):

From a standard SE perspective, I would not advise asking the same question again - it would (or, at least, should) probably get closed as duplicate.  So, you pretty much have two options remaining.  These can be done separately or in conjunction:

1. Post a comment to the existing answer(s) with your concerns.
2. Post a bounty to the question, asking for the details you need.

   - On Beta sites, this requires a minimum reputation of 100 but will cost at least 50 rep to post.